# Unable To Close Custom ContextMenu Window

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

Everything in my WPF program is generally custom. In this problem I have a custom menu button that acts kind of like the [MS Office button](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/what-happened-to-the-file-menu-HA010120473.aspx) from 2007. When clicked it brings down a context menu. My problem is trying to get it to close. After being opened, the Context Menu never closes. I would like if it would close when the user clicks anywhere outside of the menu box, like how a normal Context Menu would act.

This is what I have so far:

.xaml Window:

```
<!--- MAIN MENU BUTTON -->
        <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Margin="5,4,0,0" Name="Button_1" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="49.758">
            <!--- MAIN MENU -->
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu" PlacementRectangle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" MouseLeave="ContextMenuMouseLeave" >
                    ...                
            </Button.ContextMenu>
```

Right now I am just trying to get it to close when the mouse leaves the menu, because I do not know what keyword to use when I am describing a click outside of the Context menu. As you can see, when the mouse leaves the menu, the program calls the "ContextMenuMouseLeave" function.

.xaml.cs code-behind:

```
//CLOSE CONTEXT MENU
        private void ContextMenuMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainContextMenu.IsOpen = false;
        }
```

Apparently in WPF the Context Menu object does not contain `Close()`, or `Hide()`. I have also tried `MyContextMenu.IsOpen = false;` and `SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");` with no luck. How do I get this menu window to close again in WPF??

-I've posted this question on another forum as well and I was wondering if maybe a Context Menu isn't the best way to go? Apparently Context Menus are mainly displayed when a used right clicks something. I'm going to be using this button to open my program's main menu. **Should I be using some other object?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set **MainContextMenu.Visibility** to **Visibility.Collapsed**